# Node npm install error

Tags: node.js, npm

I've just reinstall my windows to windows 10. I've installed node 5.0. 
But the problem is when everytime I try to do "npm install" it got me like that. I waited for it to finish and I can't use the gulp.

[image: npm install]

What should I do to make it working again?

Comment: Make sure the path given by `npm -g prefix` is included in the `PATH` environment variable for your Windows account. [How do I set system environment variables in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) Completely uninstalling and reinstalling Node may set this for you, barring any [`npmrc` files](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) on your system that may point it to another path. Also, make sure you don't interrupt the `install` by typing `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: will try. ctrl+c is when i tried it still like that. I've tried almost 30 times with result still like that. Update: I've added the PATH. but it's not working. it still like that

Comment: Note that you'll need to restart PowerShell for it to pick up changes to the `PATH` variable. Then, if you try `ls (npm -g prefix)`, are `gulp` and `gulp.cmd` included in the list? If they are, what does `gcm gulp` tell you?

Comment: I even restary my computer. But not working. Every time i run npm install -g gulp it keep gtting me that view. I can't install it. no gulp and gulp.cmd is not in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like node 5.0 breaks it. I revert to Node 4.2.2 and it works perfectly again.